# Accordion won't take up height of chart for first click

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I've run into a problem with my code to where I have an accordion and when it's clicked on, won't take up the height of my chart that I did in Chart JS. However, when I toggle it again. It takes up the height as necessary. What I'm trying to figure out is when I click on the accordion I want the chart to be loaded right after with it's animation.

I want the chart to drop down and load. It's doing what I want but I cannot figure out why the accordion won't take up the height on the first click and does when I toggle it again?

Here is my code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fast-factsv2">
<div class="fastfactssubContainer">
    <h1><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true" alt="Fast Facts"></i><span id="subheaderspan">Simple Heading</span></h1>

    <div class="accordionContainer">
        <h2>Simple Heading</h2>
        <button class="accordion" id="chart1">
            <span>1. Simple Heading</span>
        </button>
        <div class="panel">
            <canvas id="container1" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

 for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      } 
    }
 }
```

```js
//Doughnut Chart
$("#chart1").one("click", function(){
  var popChart = new Chart(container1, {
    responsive: true,
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      datasets:[{
        data: [38],
        backgroundColor:['#ea7738']
      }],
      labels:['Median Age'],
    },
    options: {
      cutoutPercentage: 95
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.fastfactssubContainer h1 {
  font-size: 40px; }

.fastfactssubContainer {
  background: #fff;
  opacity: .9;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 50%; }
  .fastfactssubContainer .accordionContainer h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-top: 10px; }
  .fastfactssubContainer h1 {
    padding: 30px 30px 0 30px; }
  .fastfactssubContainer .fa {
    color: #000;
    padding-right: 33px; }
  .fastfactssubContainer #subheaderspan {
    color: #57bcf2; }

.accordionContainer {
  margin: 0 100px 100px 100px; }
  .accordionContainer i.fa.fa-heart-o, .accordionContainer i.fa.fa-share-alt {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 16px;
    color: #b6b6b6; }
  .accordionContainer h2 {
    padding-right: 10px; }
  .accordionContainer span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px; }
  .accordionContainer button.accordion {
    background: transparent;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #6f6f6f;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
    outline: none; }
    .accordionContainer button.accordion button.accordion.active, .accordionContainer button.accordion:hover {
      /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
      background-color: #ddd; }

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
div.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out; }

button.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795';
  /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px; }

button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */ }

#container1 {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative; }
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to include the accordion javascript.

Comment: Figured it out. I just needed to add height to the accordion itself.

Answer (score 0):

I added `width: 100%` in your CSS:

```
#container1 {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

Works for me